# Android build.gradle.kts Unable to use "main" DSL for sourceSets. Error: "Expression 'main' cannot be invoked as a function"

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Gradle AGP: 8.0.0.

I've tried following the Gradle docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html
I tried to add this example block into my build.gradle.kts file:

`sourceSets { main { java.srcDir("src/core/java") } }`

However, I get an error:
Expression 'main' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

Is there anything I need to set up before Android Studio can recognise it?

I've looked through the context actions for importing but it only provides a whole list of main functions.